# How to wipe specific area in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

I'm trying to make canvas draw code for the purposes of electronics education. 
Please take a look at: http://3lectronics.com/draw/Atarado-Draw1.html

Trying to make script for electronics layout on Atarado prototyping board, and I'm just JS very beginner. I stacked with erasing part of the canvas (yes I know that should be work with SVG, but with it I'm comfortable a lot).

Also know that draw on canvas is like simple paint program working with pixels, but those programs have kind of tool for wiping bitmap part of area...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [canvas.clearRect(x1,y1,x2,y2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Rectangles), or fillRect with a white color.

Comment: Thanx TJ, but "No can do, sir!"

Comment: TJ I have to apologize!
It works, I just to have switch it to ghost canvas.

Comment: I guess you upvoted it, use the green arrow beneath that to mark it as answer ;)